# Intelligent screen scraping using different proxies and user-agents randomly?

Tags: python, proxy, screen-scraping

I want to download few HTML pages from **http://abc.com/view_page.aspx?ID=**  The ID is from an array of different numbers.

I would be interested in visiting multiple instances of this URL and saving the file as [ID].HTML using different proxy IP/ports.

I want to use different user-agents and I want to randomize the wait times before each download.

What is the best way of doing this? urllib2? pycURL? cURL? What do you prefer for the task at hand?

Please advise. Thanks guys!

Comment: Why would you want to randomize the user-agents?

Comment: I don't want to reveal that I am the one downloading the page. To step it up, if we use different browsers randomly, that will solidify my anonymity, what do you say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like:

```
import urllib2
import time
import random

MAX_WAIT = 5
ids = ...
agents = ...
proxies = ...

for id in ids:
    url = 'http://abc.com/view_page.aspx?ID=%d' % id
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http' : proxies[0]}))
    html = opener.open(urllib2.Request(url, None, {'User-agent': agents[0]})).read()
    open('%d.html' % id, 'w').write(html)
    agents.append(agents.pop()) # cycle
    proxies.append(proxies.pop())
    time.sleep(MAX_WAIT*random.random())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use unix tool `wget`. It has option to specify custom user-agent and delay between each retrieval of the page.

You can see [wget(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) for more information.

Comment: That is a good start, thank you! --random-wait can be used. Not so sure about proxy implementation though. Any ideas?

Comment: I have only used `wget` for basic scrapping, so sorry, I cannot give you more info about proxying with it.

Comment: Using a proxy in wget:

    setenv http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:8080;
    wget --proxy-user=foo --proxy-password=bar --user-agent="Frobzilla/1.1" [url]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use open proxies, checkout [ProxyMesh](http://proxymesh.com), which does IP rotation/randomization for you.